# Ternary Operator on badges to reveal badges only when there is a new message

Tags: flutter, dart, ternary-operator

might be a simple problem to solve.

I'm trying to show the badges icon on the chat screen only if there are unread messages.

The default number of badges has already been set to '0'.

How do I code the ternary operator such that it doesn't even appear if there are no unread messages, and appear only if there is at least one unread messages?

Issue I'm having, badges are appearing even when unread messages is zero (embedded in the following link):

[image]

```
 new Container(
                margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                child: new InkWell(
                    child: new Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                      new Badge(
                          badgeColor: Colors.green[300],
                          badgeContent: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.0, right: 3),
                            child: Text('${badges ?? ''}' == 0
                                ? ''
                                : '${badges ?? ''}'),
                          ))
                    ]))),
```

Comment: Additional thoughts: Trying to make the badge totally not present, when there is no new message. So the code above should be wrong. The ternary operator should be outside of the badge or might even be outside of 'Container' or 'Inkwell' itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
badges > 0
? new Container(
    margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
    child: new InkWell(
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Badge(
            badgeColor: Colors.green[300],
            badgeContent: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.0, right: 3),
              child: Text('$badges'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
: CustomWidget() //Return what you want here
```

You can nest the ternary operator to put the condition on deeper widgets.

Comment: tried this method, flutter said I cannot use the operator '>' on null which was '0' in this case.

Comment: What’s the type of the variable `badges`? I’d advise to make it an int and initialize it to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Solved. (badges == null) worked.

Answer (score 0):

basically you have a logic that will check if badges is equal to '0' then just return a blank container

```
children: <Widget>[
   (badges == '0') ? Container() : Badge( ... ),
]
```

Comment: Tried this method, it returned a text 'null' within the badge for those badges with no new messages

Comment: it only means that the badges is being set to null in your code... so replace it this way `(badges ?? '0' == '0')`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Solved. (badges == null) worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
(badges == null) 
? new Container(
    margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
    child: new InkWell(
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Badge(
            badgeColor: Colors.green[300],
            badgeContent: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.0, right: 3),
              child: Text('$badges'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
: CustomWidget()
```

worked. Thank you.

badge was initialized as an int to 0 above

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution
isLabelVisible: false